# validation in javascript for a php loop

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am trying to make a simple validation in javascript for a foreach in php, but I don't know how to parse each row from view

```
<table>
<?php $i=1; ?>
 <?php foreach($questions $row): 
 ?>
<tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo $i++; ?><?php echo  $row->question;?></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo  $row->category;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo  $row->id;?></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="r" value="<?php echo  $row->var_1;?>"></td>
<td class="answer"><?php echo  $row->var_a;?></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="r" value="<?php echo  $row->var_2;?>"></td>
<td class="answer"><?php echo  $row->var_b;?></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="r" value="<?php echo  $row->var_3;?>"></td>
<td class="answer"><?php echo  $row->var_c;?></td?
</tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<button type="button" id="submit">Send</button>
```

And in javascript I try to check every answer for each question .

```
<script>
    $("#submit").on("click", function(){     
     var x=0;
        if(document.getElementById("r").checked == true document.getElementById("r").value == 1){
            x=x+1;
        }
}); 
</script>
```

Each answer has value 1 or 0, and it can be multiple choice.

Comment: Why don't you validate it in PHP rather than mashing it into JS?

Comment: Because if it is correct answer , I want to put color background for answer..

Answer (score 0):

1. IDs need to be Unique - use class or name instead
2. if you have jQuery USE jQuery

---

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e){     
 var x=$(".r:checked").length; // using class="r"
 if (x < $(".r").length) {
   alert("Please check all checkboxes");
   e.preventDefault();
 }
});
```

or using name="r"

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e){     
 var x=$('input[name="r"]:checked').length; 
 if (x < $('input[name="r"]').length) {
   alert("Please check all checkboxes");
   e.preventDefault();
 }
});
```